# Where do I place helper files?

Tags: 8

I would like to place some (PHP)functions in a helper files, which requires across modules and themes.

Do I have to create a new module or I can place a simple helper file with list of common functions, what is the best practice for these kind of functions in drupal 8 ?

Comment: Common practice you see a lot in contrib modules is to place a new class in your module's `/src` directory and then have a service calling them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create a utility module, so your consumer modules can [declare a dependency](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/let-drupal-8-know-about-your-module-with-an-infoyml-file) to the utility module in their `.info.yml` file. Optionally to keep the admin UI clean you could use `hidden: true` in the utility module's `.info.yml`

(I assumed you are speaking of a very drupal-specific helper lib, not some general purpose library like e.g. Guzzle that would go into composer)